# vulnserver - Can't find JMP ESP in ntdll.dll

Tags: buffer-overflow, assembly

This tutorial shows how to find a JMP ESP in nttdll.dll

http://sh3llc0d3r.com/vulnserver-trun-command-buffer-overflow-exploit/

> 3. Find address for EIP
>
> In this step we have to check the registers and the stack. We have to
> find a way to jump to our buffer to execute our code. ESP points to
> the beginning of the C part of our buffer. We have to find a JMP ESP
> or CALL ESP instruction. Do not forget, that the address must not
> contain bad characters!
>
> Open the executable modules list in OllyDbg (press the E letter on the
> toolbar). Select a module, for example the ntdll.dll. (Vulnserv would
> not be a good choice as its address contains zero!)
>
> Press right click on the code and select Search for/All commands.
> Enter JMP ESP. A couple of possible address is displayed. Select one.

I've followed the steps but couldn't find JMP ESP instruction in nttdll.dll.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few executable modules in your screenshot. In your case, `nttdll.dll` doesn't has `JMP ESP` instruction.

The right tool for this is [mona.py](https://github.com/corelan/mona)

> mona.py is a tool written in Python and available with Immunity
> Debugger that helps finding a reliable JMP ESP instruction.

https://www.whitelist1.com/2016/11/xstack-overflow-1-exploiting-slmail.html

To find all addresses with `JMP ESP`, use `!mona jmp -r esp` command.

This command will search in the loaded executable modules for a memory address that has `JMP ESP`.

https://medium.com/@johntroony/a-practical-overview-of-stack-based-buffer-overflow-7572eaaa4982